# Access a container with http works but failed with httpS

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ssl, gcloud

#### Summary

I have a cluster with a container inside a pod I can access trough http. But since I try to replace http by https, it failed.

#### Explanations

So, when I set the cluster with the config files on “All the config files”’s section, I am able to use the server trough `http://<Cluster IP>` And I get the “Hello world” outputted by Gunicorn.

The relevant section is on the following `service.yaml` section:

```yaml
  - name: https
    nodePort: 32114
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: http
    nodePort: 32115
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
```

As you see, both http and https are configured to talk into the port 8080 of the pod, but http works when I open `http://<Cluster IP>` —Without http**S**— and https failed with the following error:

```json
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {},
  "code": 403
}
```

#### The question

So, how can I just get the same behaviour with httpS than with http, and make the cluster redirect request to the pod as he do in http?

#### **Appendix** — All the config files

##### `deployment.yaml`

I get the following files with `kubectl get [deployment|service|pod] <name> -o yaml > file.yaml`.

(The four-dashed lines represent eclipsed lines I found useless)

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "7"
  creationTimestamp: "2024-02-28T10:28:54Z"
  generation: 9
  name: deploiement-gke-calcul-distances
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1264625"
  ----
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  ----
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-gunicorn
  ----
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: app-gunicorn
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/<Project name>/gunicorn
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: gunicorn-container
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 80
          name: http-port
          protocol: TCP
        ----
      ----
```

##### `service.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
  creationTimestamp: "2024-02-27T18:26:19Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    component: apiserver
    provider: kubernetes
  name: kubernetes
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1265272"
  uid: <UID>
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  clusterIP: <Cluster IP>
  clusterIPs:
  - <Cluster IP>
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: https
    nodePort: 32114
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: http
    nodePort: 32115
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: <Load Balancer IP>
```

##### `pod.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-02-28T14:31:49Z"
  generateName: <Pod Name>-
  labels:
    app: app-gunicorn
    pod-template-hash: 966c8cccc
  name: <Pod Name>-k5dls
  namespace: default
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: <Pod Name>
    uid: 43fc51fd-ee3e-4012-a4f9-89c9db7ff5a4
  resourceVersion: "1264618"
  uid: ede731c1-9a14-4642-9f64-44c9a4dbc442
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/<Project name>/gunicorn
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: gunicorn-container
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      hostPort: 80
      name: http-port
      protocol: TCP
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-n6spk
      readOnly: true
----
```

##### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM debian:11

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -yq \
&& apt-get install -yq python3 python3-pip\
&& pip3 install flask geopy googlemaps gunicorn python-dotenv

WORKDIR /app

COPY workingfile/ /app

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-b", ":8080", "app:app"]
```

##### Kubectl output on verification

```
% kubectl get services ; kubectl get deployments ; kubectl get pods

NAME                TYPE          CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP        PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes          LoadBalancer  <Cluster IP> <Load Balancer IP> 80:32115/TCP   21h
NAME                READY         UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
<Deployment name>   1/1           1            1           5h47m
NAME                READY         STATUS       RESTARTS   AGE
<Pod Name>-k5dls    1/1           Running      0          104m
```

Comment: Hi @fauve, I don't know much about Kubernetes but did you specify anywhere a certificate (even self-signed)? I'd expect you need one to set up HTTPS.

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/@seifeddinerajhi/from-http-to-https-enabling-https-only-kubernetes-ingress-with-cert-manager-ad2ff06e5b85) seems to corrobore with my observation